# Visual Studio Templates and environment variables

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, project-template

I have created a project template for Visual Studio 2010, and I have an environment variable I setted up in every machine I use. The template references some resources which are located in the directory pointed in that environment variable. 
A sample reference in the template is:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="$(MyVariable)OneDir\MyFile.txt">
```

The key point is that when I create a proyect with this template, and in the .csproj I get:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="..\..\..\..\Users\MyUser\AppData\......."/>
```

In the same .csproj I have replace it in the .csproj file whit:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="$(MyVariable)OneDir\MyFile.txt">
```

So, is there any way to make the csproj writes "$(MyVariable" in the "Include" parameter?.
I have tried with the scape caracter %24 which correspond  to the "$" character like it is saying in msdn [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx but i get this .csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="%24..\..\..\..\Users\MyUser\AppData\......."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try workaround used [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399589/msbuild-include-files-based-on-a-group-of-paths). It is about creating property from env variable and using it inside ItemGroup.